# Compress a folder but skip compressing specific file types and include them as such

Tags: scripts, backup, tar, compression, gzip

I am using tar with pigz to compress a folder and save a backup. Size of this folder ~190 GB or more. This folder has variety of content including numerous text and log files, ISOs and zip files in many different sub-folders. 
Full compression of this folder takes around 1 hour (or more sometimes). At this moment I use this in a script.

`tar -cf -  <data_folder>  | pigz  -1  >  <output_file>.tar.$`

I want to reduce the compression time by excluding compression on ISOs and zip files. I want them (ISOs and zip files) to be included in the gzip file as such.

**My question is this:** Is it possible to selectively compress files based on type, and still include uncompressed files in the gzip output. How to try this out.

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, it is possible - if you compress each of files you want compressed separately, leaving the rest uncompressed, and then just add them - contents of your folder to archive as they are, with tar without compression. May not be very convenient, but would get you what you want. The way you try to do it right now - it won't rather work like that. If you put entire directory into archive and pipe it to gzip/pigz - whatever is in that archive, gzip will compress it. If you want to speed up the process a bit, you can also reduce the compression level, to gain some speed at the cost of size.

Comment: Of course you can generally exclude some files from the tar - but those, basically, will not be added to archive at all. gzip/pigz as such works on single file, so there's not really much to exclude on that level. However, you can automate the process maybe adding some extra commands to make a list of what's in your directory, exclude iso or whatever other types you want excluded from compression, then compress all the rest and in next step tar the folder. ("find" may be useful with selecting files to compress, I'd say)

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Compression level is minimum now. Your idea about making a list and tar is a good one.